# (rails) moment object displayed as being mutated, but .hours() is correct

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, momentjs

I have initializations that look like this:

```
var date = moment(arrValue.start_date).add(5, 'hours');
var dummy = date.clone();
var date2 = dummy.add(arrValue.duration, 'hours');
```

I have a for loop that looks like this:

```
for(var d = date.clone(); d.isBefore(date2); d.add(1, 'hours')) {
   console.log(d);
   console.log(d.hour());
   unavailableDates.push(d);
}
```

In each iteration, the console.log for d has the same value

_d: Mon Mar 05 2018 16:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)

This ^ is the value that console.log(date2) would include. 
It iterates the correct amount of times and the console.log(d.hour()) displays the correct hour, but the object d itself is for some reason incorrect so that when I push it to unavailableDates, each index always contains the value of date2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are mutating and adding the same object to the array on each iteration.  This means at the end of the iterations, every object in the array will be the same object, with the final mutation.  To avoid this, you can clone the object within the iteration, for instance:

```
for(var d = date.clone(); d.isBefore(date2); d.add(1, 'hours')) {
  console.log(d);
  console.log(d.hour());
  x = d.clone()
  unavailableDates.push(x);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know why that didn't occur to me before, that seems so obvious.